# Access to geoserver (hosted on EC2) from a website

Tags: amazon-ec2, leaflet, geoserver

I have set up a geoserver (ubuntu) hosted on EC2 to serve my tiles (WMS). My website can access the tiles with Leaflet when ran locally (http://127.0.0.1:8000/).

However, when I deploy the site on line (https://www.example.com), I get the following error in the console:
net::ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR

I opened the EC2 Inbound and Outbound rules to https - everywhere.

I guess it has something to do with the "proxy URL" in Geoserver global configuration. I am not very familiar with proxies and I don't understand what I am supposed to put here. When I put "www.example.com", it still does not work.

Any clue ? Thanks a lot

Comment: Default port for geoserver is 8080. Can you clarify what did you do exactly? You bought a domain (www.example.com) which points to your instance? They you are using https to access it, but do you have ssl certificates setup? If so, how did you set them up? Does your server work without https, `http://www.example.com` (not `https://www.example.com`)?

Comment: I use "http://127.0.0.1:8000" when I run the website locally. The remote site is hosted on render.com. I bought a domain name on namecheap.com. Sites hosted on Render come with fully managed and free SSL certificates from Let’s Encrypt. On namecheap, I followed these instructions render.com/docs/configure-namecheap-dns and created A record and CNAME record. When a user connects to http:// www.example.com, he is automatically redirected to https:// www.example.com to secure access. Does it answer your question ? Do you I need to create a certificate for the EC2 instance hosting geoserver ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the issue is you're trying to access the website using HTTPS while the application is being served using HTTP

to configure SSL

https://hackmd.io/@0plKX4z5TGSOwOm65xoKoA/Bkvj2OGoM?type=view